# .net Razor render concatenated text with no space

Tags: razor

I have:

```
 @:<img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/lesson_icon/")@mi.LessonId .png" />
```

But it renders as `...lesson_icon/d40d2ff2-d06b-4fd8-80a0-0ed31bbc04eb%20.png`

How can I get rid of the `%20` in front of `.png` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a space before your file extension that you should remove there:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/content/images/lesson_icon/{0}.png", mi.LessonId))" />
```

or if you are using Razor v2 you could try that:

```
<img src="~/content/images/lesson_icon/@(mi.LessonId).png" />
```

Comment: ^^^^ exactly as above

Answer (score 0):

You can send a string with the complete link, for example:

```
string path = "../content/images/lesson_icon/"
string link = path + mi.LessonId + ".png";
```

And send that in the model, or you can try:

```
@{string png = ".png"}
@:<img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/lesson_icon/")@mi.LessonId + @png />
```